# How to access private members of a private type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c++-loki

I want to access private members without modifying the .h file.
This is an example of a .h file

```cpp
class X
{
private:
   class A
   {...};
   vector<A> arr;
}
```

Q:How can I access X::arr ?

```cpp
class X
{
private:
    int a;
};

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type Member>
struct XAccessor 
{ 
    friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) 
    {
        return Member;
    } 
};

struct X_A
{ 
    typedef int X::* type;
    friend type get(X_A);
};;

template struct XAccessor<X_A, &X::a>;

...
auto x = new X;
x->*get(X_A())=11;
...
```

I found this approach online, but when I changed `typedef int X::* type` to `typedef vector<X::A> X::* type`, it gave me an error saying that `X::A` is not accessible.

Comment: Why do you want to access private members? The whole point of non-public members is to *not* allow access to them. Perhaps your design is flawed to begin with?

Comment: Also please ask about the *underlying*, *actual* and *real* problem you try to solve, instead of asking us to help you with a solution to an for us unknown problem. There might be other solutions possible. Right now your question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: It's not clear to me why `X` needs to access `private` members of `X::A` since, even if `X::A` members are `public`, they will only be accessible to `X` (and `friend`s of `X`).   But options include (1) `X::A()` provide appropriate `public` setters and getters that set/get values of private members (2) make the relevant members of `X::A` be `public` (3)   `X::A` declare `X` as a `friend`.    All of those options, however, mean that it is pointless for `X::A` to have `private` members that `X` needs to access.

Answer (score 8):

If you can steal the data member pointer, you can extract the type from it. Here is a solution that works with zero modifications to the original `X`.

Say we have a class `X` which we can't modify, containing a private data member of private type `Hidden`. In your example, `Hidden = std::vector<A>`.

```cpp
class X
{
private:
    struct Hidden {};
    Hidden a;
};
```

We can create a function that returns the data member pointer `X::*a`, without naming the type `X::Hidden`:

```cpp
// the following three declarations give us a data member pointer to X::a
auto steal();

template <auto Ptr>
struct Thief {
    friend auto steal() {
        return Ptr;
    }
};

// explicit instantiation of specialization Thief<&X::a>
template struct Thief<&X::a>;
```

The reason why this works is that member access restrictions are disabled when explicitly instantiating templates, so `Thief<&X::a>` will not fail to compile.
This is intentional design, because otherwise you would be unable to explicitly instantiate any templates involving non-public members.

`Thief` defines a hidden friend `steal()`, which returns the data member pointer, and acts as a "jailbreak" for encapsulation.
`steal()` is just a free function, and doesn't contain `&X::a` or `X::Hidden` in any template parameters or function parameters, so nothing restricts our access to it.

We also create a type trait so we can extract the data type from this pointer:

```cpp
// trait which lets us extract Hidden from a data member pointer
template <typename T>
struct member_type;

template <typename C, typename M>
struct member_type<M C::*> {
    using type = M;
};
```

Finally, we are able to access both the private type `X::Hidden`, and the private data member `X::a`:

```cpp
// X_Hidden = X::Hidden
using X_Hidden = member_type<decltype(steal())>::type;

// steal private data member at runtime
X_Hidden get_a(const X &x) {
    X_Hidden X::*a = steal();
    return x.*a;
}
```

See [live demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vGhYhYvWz).

Comment: I am close to downvoting:  yes it works technically. It is broken on the design level, the private keyword was added to explicitly hide a member and accessing private members directly might break the invariants the class is trying to protect. so DO NOT DO THIS it is bound to break something in bigger projects.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'll give OP the benefit of the doubt and assume that they have been cornered by legacy code bases and strange requirements, and are left not other choice. Anyhow, the question wasn't whether you should do it, but how to do it. When OP asks "how do I shoot myself in the foot?", my only job is to tell them how to turn the safety off and pull the trigger :3

Comment: I wish I understood this code. I think the first part I don't understand is `template struct Thief<&X::a>`. Could you explain that please?

Comment: Yes that is the one reason you might need to do it. And then still OP should still make a change request at the provider of the class. And just to make clear and don't want to downvote your effort, I just want to have made it clear (for anyone visiting later) that this is a panic solution.

Comment: Note that in C++20 (and in many implementations of prior versions) you can do this with explicit specializations instead of explicit instantiations, which avoids the need for the friend-injection trick.  If we're going to destroy the world, we should do it in as clean a fashion as possible!